# Sort by 'Views' on Main Question Pages Next to 'Votes'

Tags: feature-request, questions, stack-exchange, sorting

One thing I love about the stack exchange sites, is that I can quickly and easily sort any of the questions by the number of votes.  What would be even better is if I could quickly and easily sort by views.  That way I could see some good questions that did not receive as many votes, but are beloved anyway.

I've seen some people pointing out that some query string values will let you see all the questions for a fixed number of views.  This is nice and all, but not very fun to use or as useful as it could be.

Also, I've read some other similarly themed proposals, but I don't think any of them state it as frankly as here.  Most of those other proposals are mollified when the asker finds that they can pass in a query string value.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer? I know the sql is rough. I might need a hand to clean it up from your friendly StackOverflow data engine legend Sam Saffron.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this would be a nice feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured&**filter=viewcount** but realistically it is quite a big ask.

In the mean time, I whipped up this query that will list questions from the start of the month ordered by ViewCount, please give it a go over at: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

```
SELECT 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/' +  CONVERT(varchar,P.id),
P.CreationDate,P.Score, P.ViewCount, P.Title,P.Tags,P.Body, P.AnswerCount 
FROM Posts P
WHERE P.CreationDate >= convert(datetime, '01/06/2012', 103)
ORDER BY P.ViewCount DESC
```

ps It took 38 sec's to run.